# How to tell what index is trying to be used for ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem)

Tags: indexing, sitecore, sitecore7.2

So, ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem) is returning null. Im pretty sure we might be missing an index. When using the sitecore master database, everything works fine, but in web is null.

I guess the question is, is there a way to know which index is GetIndex trying to recover that is returning null.

Comment: It seems the index you are passing to the GetIndex does not exists. From the showconfig.aspx page, check if all your web index files are being loaded.

Comment: Im not passing an index, im passing the indexable index to let GetIndex resolve the more suitable index in this case. Which is none it seems.

Comment: Can you please provide how you implement it. I mean a code snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't overriden the default Sitecore logic for getting the index, Sitecore checks all the indexes which are registered in the configuration and for each of them, it checks if the `SitecoreIndexableItem` passed to the

```
ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem)
```

is not excluded from that index.

Then is simply returns **the first matching index**.

So the answer to your question is - Sitecore check all indexes if they are a match for your item.

You may want to look through your logs for an error like this:

> "There is no appropriate index for {indexable.AbsolutePath} - {indexable.Id}. You have to add an index crawler that will cover this item"

This may help you find which item is not indexed at all.

Comment: I will take a look, but so far, i haven't found such an error. I would love to see a way to output all that check logic somewhere.

Comment: Ok, this took me to the root of my specific problem, using the info here: http://elenazlateva.blogspot.com/2014/10/vulnerability-with-using-sitecore.html I iterated through the indexes and crawlers and figured which index crawler's root was erroring out. I would say it is a bug in sitecore erroring out before analyzing all indexes because of a missing null check.

Comment: @Ernesto Nicely spotted!

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct since it helped me understand that it wasn't sitecore trying to use an index and not finding it but testing each index as a candidate.